# Always open certain links in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, windows-shell

I know this gets asked a bit, I've been reading things about it all day.  I know, this is horrible.  Sadly, we have a single link on our page that launches a Silverlight tool, and while we wait for an HTML5 version, we need to do this.

I read up a few SO answers and ended up with this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rVL]
@="URL:HyperText Transfer Protocol"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rVL\Application]
"AppUserModelID"="Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default"
"ApplicationCompany"="@C:\\Windows\\System32\\ieframe.dll,-55177"
"ApplicationDescription"="@C:\\Windows\\System32\\ieframe.dll,-55176"
"ApplicationName"="@C:\\Windows\\System32\\ieframe.dll,-55175"
"ApplicationIcon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rVL\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\url.dll,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rVL\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rVL\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rVL\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" \"%1\""
```

This works.  If I create a HTML file with a link to `rVL://www.microsoft.com`, it launches IE.  Sadly, it keeps the `rVL://`, which means the browser can't run it, it doesn't recognize it.  I have experimented with using `%2`, but I can't figure a way for an anchor tag to pass two parameters through, I end up with an empty URL.

My registry keys are based on the `IE.HTTP` key. So, I tried just using `IE.HTTP:// www.microsoft.com`.  This causes IE to open and then close. In fact, that key has items I have removed to get to what you see above, which got me to the point I am now (link opens, does not work because of invalid prefix).

I've found IETab and I think it could work, but, it requires our users to do a bit of configuring. It's bad enough I expect to make them download and run a `.reg` file.  Either way, it's a challenge at this point, so, any suggestions on how I can add a new prefix that allows a link to launch IE, AND run the link, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just fyi, Silverlight is no longer being maintained [ref](http://www.favbrowser.com/rip-microsoft-silverlight/)

Comment: Not sure I understandard the initial problem?

Comment: OK - the problem is simple - I know Silverlight is not being maintained.  But, IE still opens it with no complaint, and Chrome and FF do not.  So, we wanted a link that forces a Chrome page, to open a new page in IE.  At this stage, we're not going ahead with it.  I don't think there's any better solutions than what I've found.  I knew asking here was a long shot, thanks all the same.

To clarify, we're using a third party component and it's being rewritten in HTML5, this was a stop gap solution